# How to parse a document from my Firestore Database

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I parse the data from my Firestore. My  Document looks like:[image: Produkte is an array. The Array includes maps with a String and a Number]

with this code, I get my data.

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection("Benutzer").document("Anton").collection("Einkaufsliste").snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return  ExpansionTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID),
                    children: buildCheckBoxListTile(index, snapshot),
```

in the `buildCheckBoxListTile(index, snapshot)` Function I wanted to get the data from the maps. So, how can I parse these Data?

Thank you for help.

**Edit:**
I created a class Produkte:

```
class Produkte{
  Produkte({this.produktList});

  List<Produkt> produktList;

  factory Produkte.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    var list = parsedJson["Produkte"] as List;
    List<Produkt> products = list.map((i) => Produkt.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return Produkte(
      produktList: products,
    );
  }
}
```

And a class Produkt:

```
class Produkt{
  Produkt({this.name, this.anzahl});

  String name;
  int anzahl;

  factory Produkt.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return Produkt(
      name: parsedJson["Name"],
      anzahl: parsedJson["Anzahl"]
    );
  }
}
```

Now when i call this: `Produkte Hans = Produkte.fromJson(snapshot.data.documents[index].data);` 
the follwoing Exception is thrown:
 `I/flutter (18038): Another exception was thrown: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Comment: See https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. I am using the [json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable)  package for automatic generation.

For me it helped, to remove the cast types from the map

```
  factory Produkt.fromJson(Map parsedJson)
```

and allowed any map on the annoation

```
@JsonSerializable(anyMap: true)
```

There was an issue with some discussion over this topic in the [flutter repository](https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/issues/351). HerrNiklasRaab posted a other workaround there as well:

```
  factory Chat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    json["members"] = (json['members'] as List)
          ?.map((e) =>
              e == null ? null : Map<String, dynamic>.from(e))
          ?.toList();
     return _$ChatFromJson(json);  
  }
```

Comment: Can explane what '_$ChatFromJson(json)' is?

Comment: _$ChatFromJson is from the package "json_serializable" and a automatic generated class

Comment: @AntonSchrage i tried it with some sample data and it works. can you please post the response that you are getting from the server?

Comment: i found my mistake in another question:)